# Copy all qt resources using cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml

I would like to compile qml application using cmake.
Here is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(QMLTest)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Quick REQUIRED)

add_executable(QMLTest main.cpp)
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES})
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})
qt5_use_modules(QMLTest Widgets Quick )
```

And main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;
    view.resize(800, 480);
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("gui/MainWidnow.qml"));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

When I try to compile it I get an error:

> gui/MainWidnow.qml: File not found.

How can I copy all my qt resources into application directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of copying your QML files into the application directory, I would instead recommend using Qt's resource system ([1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)), which allows you to embed resources such as QML files directly in your executable. To do this, you need to first create a resource file such as `resources.qrc` to register your application resources:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource>
        <file>gui/MainWindow.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

You then add the resource file to your CMake configuration. This will create a source file from the resource file which you need to include in your application sources:

```
qt5_add_resources(RCC_SOURCES resources.qrc)
add_executable(QMLTest ${RCC_SOURCES} main.cpp)
```

Once this is done, you can use a file URL in the format `:/gui/MainWindow.qml` to refer to this resource, which is now embedded in your application binary. Qt will automatically resolve it for you:

```
view.setSource(QUrl(":/gui/MainWindow.qml"));
```

There are some more details in the Qt documentation on deploying QML applications ([2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html)).

Comment: The last line did not work for me, as the QUrl would look for a path like `"path/:/gui/file.qml"`. Changing it to `view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/gui/MainWindow.qml"));` did the trick

Comment: @DuKes0mE That is surprising, as according to the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) and my experience they are equivalent.

Comment: Have you tried the Qt5QuickCompiler: http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/qquickcompiler-building-with-cmake.html
Looks like in general you can replace qt5_add_resources() with qtquick_compiler_add_resources(), however I'm not sure if AUTORCC is smart enough to handle this on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to extend the accepted answer.
I would write this as a comment but I don't have the reputation.

It is possible to use Qt independent CMAKE function calls instead of `qt5_add_resources()`:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
add_executable(myexe main.cpp resource_file.qrc)
```

And then you can refer to the files using `:/file_relative_to_qrc`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that, for example:

```
add_custom_target(copy-runtime ALL
    COMMAND cmake -E copy ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/gui/MainWindow.qml
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    DEPENDS QMLTest)
```

I didn't test that, but you'll get the idea. Another option would be e.g. to use CMake's install command to install the runtime files locally with "make install". However, in this case the best option would be to use Qt's resource system like ajshort recommends in his answer and embed the needed files in the executable.

Comment: I'd prefer symolic links over copying. You might edit the wrong file or forget to re-copy.